# How to read variables from the word document using docx4j?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, docx4j

I want get to the variables(${colour}) list and then pass the variables dynamically.Is it possible to get the variables list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write code to do that yourself.

Three approaches:

1. Use TextUtils to get just the text, and parse for ${
2. Use XPath
3. Use Traverse utils

All 3 of these are documented further in docx4j's Getting Started.

Method 1 is the simplest, I guess.

Could your variables be in headers/footers/footnotes/endnotes?  If so, note these are separate "parts", and would also need to be handled.